# Cannot create non existing column in SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm executing the following query on my db:

```
alter table Client drop column "IsVersionValid"
GO
alter table Client add "IsVersionValid" bit NULL
```

with the following result:

Msg 4924, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because column 'IsVersionValid' does not exist in table 'Client'.
Msg 2705, Level 16, State 6, Line 3
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'IsVersionValid' in table 'Client' is specified more than once.

How is this possible? I'm trying to add a column that is not existing in my table. I tried doing this manually via the table designer of ssms. But this gives te same result.

Comment: Executing account is dbowner? Just thinking.

Comment: are you sure, you have `double quotes` in the column name  ?

Comment: Double Quotes (`"`) in SQL Server *can* be used to delimit identify; provided `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is set to `ON`, @SudiptaMondal . `SELECT * FROM "dbo"."MyTable";` and `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyTable];` are synonyms. [Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples)

Comment: @Larnu oh! alrighty.

Comment: I [can't replicate your problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=76e89103ec6c0c2117c33de3a337fd7b)

Comment: Make sure that both statements are actually trying to modify the same table. So check that the connected database is the same one and also the schema is the same one.

Comment: @jocobdbeboer can you post the result of `sp_help 'Client'`...

Comment: The only things I can think of are an issue with permissions and/or a DDL trigger that causes the statement(s) to have non-obvious results. This will work in a clean database.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: It does work in other databases (with the same schema). So it seems to be a issue in this specific database. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I'd check to see if there's anything interesting in `sys.triggers` and `sys.server_triggers` that actively mucks with the statement execution. Database corruption can be checked with `DBCC CHECKDB` (`DBCC CHECKTABLE` on the table itself if the database is large). Beyond that, the old IT standby of "turning it off and on again" is an option: recreate the whole table and/or the whole database through scripting/data import/`sp_rename` (some downtime unavoidable, of course). As an aside, `sp_rename` possibly might also succeed at naming a new column `IsVersionValid` after creation.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me like a dream (also with double quotes), drop column if exists, and then recreate it!

```
ALTER TABLE Client
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS IsVersionValid
GO
ALTER TABLE Client ADD IsVersionValid bit NULL
```

Comment: This also doosn't work. This is the result I'm getting when I execute your query:
Msg 2705, Level 16, State 6, Line 4
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'IsVersionValid' in table 'Client' is specified more than once.

The strange thing is that this column doos not exist, but I can't add it either, because it seem to exist. I can't see the column when I'm browsing the table structure in SSMS. It looks like some kind of schema corruption.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by creating a new table with the SELECT INTO statement. I then dropped the original table and renamed the new table. I think something was corrupted in this specific database. Other customers did not have this problem.